# Replacing numeric string of varying lengths with characters in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with alphanumeric strings. I am trying to replace the numeric part of the string with "nnnn". The length of the numeric part does not matter.

| Example: | What I am expecting |
| --- | --- |
| #100001032218888example1 | #nnnnexamplennnn |
| #1example2 | #nnnnexamplennnn |

Comment: what have you tried? can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: I tried str_replace_all(trigger_target, "[:digit:]", "nnnn"), but now I corrected it to: str_replace_all(col_name, "\\d+", "nnnn")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub()` here as follows:

```r
x <- c("#100001032218888example1", "#1example2")
output <- gsub("\\d+", "nnnn", x)
output

[1] "#nnnnexamplennnn" "#nnnnexamplennnn"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I corrected my code to: str_replace_all(col_name, "\\d+", "nnnn")